find directories only two levels deep
The command find REPORT?? -type d produces a list of all directories and subdirectories.
REPORT53
REPORT53/53233 Review
REPORT53/53233 Review/Photo
REPORT53/53233 Review/Files

I'm trying to limit output to only REPORT?? and ONE level of directory within those. I do NOT want 'Photo' and 'Files' in output. Perhaps using -name or -path; but I have not been able to get anything that works.

Use -mindepth and -maxdepth

Not using find, but I usually brute force it with something like ls -d REPORT*/*/*/

Always man find ;)
In this case, you want to use -maxdepth 2 as a search criterion:
    find REPORT?? -maxdepth 1 -type d


Almost. You can either use -maxdepth 1, or something like find . -path './REPORT*' -type d -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2  Passing REPORT?? effectively removes one layer of depth.

Apparently depth value starts at zero; so I used -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1.
